# How to get multiple checkbox value on button click?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

```
<td><p><input  class="checkbox"  type="checkbox" value="Cars.id"> </p> </td>
```

this is list of cars id with checkbox.

```
     <button (click)="duplicate()" ><ion-icon  name="color-wand"></ion-icon> </button>
```

on this button click  i want to get value of all cars in my .ts file.
here is the function in .ts

```
duplicate(){
    var checkedValue = document.querySelector('.messageCheckbox:checked');
}
```

Comment: Multiple elements with the same ID is invalid HTML. You should fix that.

Comment: You can follow this approach to handling mul. checkboxes https://netbasal.com/handling-multiple-checkboxes-in-angular-forms-57eb8e846d21

Comment: Can you please describe how this code must be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get values of selected multiple checkboxes, No  need to use DOM selectors as given in above answers you can do this in angular way.

In order to get all values of checkbox, there are several ways are available in Angular. In this answer I'll show you without using any formArray. like this -

```
<div *ngFor="let Car of Cars">
      <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(Car.id, $event.target.checked)"> {{Car.email}}<br>
  </div>

<button (click)="duplicate()" >Get values </button> 
 ----------------------------
emailFormArray: Array<any> = [];
  Cars = [ 
    {email:"email1", id: 1},
    {email:"email2", id: 2},
    {email:"email3", id: 3},
    {email:"email4", id: 4}
  ];

  onChange(email:string, isChecked: boolean) {
      if(isChecked) {
        this.emailFormArray.push(email);
      } else {
        let index = this.emailFormArray.indexOf(email);
        this.emailFormArray.splice(index,1);
      }
  }

  duplicate() {
    console.log(this.emailFormArray);
  }
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-peevcc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks alot Pradeep :)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you do not duplicated ids.

You can use `document.querySelector()` to query the dom and get the values.

```
<td> <p>  <input id="checkbox1" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Audi"> </p> /td>
<td> <p>  <input id="checkbox2" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="BMW"> </p> /td>
<td> <p>  <input id="checkbox3" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Tesla"> </p> /td>

var checkedValue = document.querySelector('.messageCheckbox:checked').value;
```

In Angular you could try to use the directive `input[checkbox]` more info here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: We need to avoid DOM Selectors as much as we can in Angular

Comment: @PardeepJain why don't you suggest a answer, instead of commenting other's effort on answer. You see OP has no models in the checkbox and why using Javascript is bad in AngularJS?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal , I was just suggesting answerers not just commenting, Whenever I get time i'll post my answer as well.

Comment: when there is functionality present in Angular then why to use DOM selectors, it may cause problem while server-side rendering in future. thats why asked for the same to avoid

Comment: Perhaps this links is of your interest: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: @PardeepJain you said `when there is functionality present in Angular ` then you should be suggesting people with that function so that they can improve there answer

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal posted as comment in question, please check

Comment: document.querySelector("checkbox:checked").value; not working

Comment: <td>
            <p>  <input  class="checkbox"  type="checkbox" value="Cars.id"> </p>
          </td>